# Vue 3 composition API typescript using ref in Object

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Hi I using Vue 3 with Typescript. In my code I have variable:

```
const editItem = ref<{
  id: number
  title: string
  author: string
}>({
  id: 0,
  title: '',
  author: '',
})
```

This variable I update using this method:

```
const updateItem = (data: {
  id: number
  title: string
  author: string
}) => {
  const { title, author } = data

  getBooks.value = getBooks.value.map(book => ({
    ...book,
    title: editItem.value.id === book.id ? title : book.title,
    author: editItem.value.id === book.id ? author : book.author,
  }))
}
```

Did this code is correctly by typescript? I readed that I should using reactive instead of ref to object, but reactive value can not be `empty`

Comment: What is `getBooks`? Does the code work as you expect it to do?